# how to compute the float nuber in Linux?

Tags: linux, math

I expect to compute the answer of the expression `a=0;b=0.055;echo $((a * 60 + b))`

however the output is as follows:

`syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".055")`

I expect the output is `0.055`

when I input : `a=0;b=0.055;echo "scale=3;a * 60 + b"|bc -l`

the output is : `0`

and input:`a=0;b=0.055;echo "scale=3;a * 60 + b"|bc`

the output is : `0`

how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were pretty close. Use `$a` and `$b` instead of just a and b like this:

```
a=0;b=0.055;echo "scale=3; (($a * 60 + $b)*100)/100"|bc
```

or in a file like this:

test.sh

```sh
#!/bin/bash

a=0
b=0.055
result=$(echo "scale=3; (($a * 60 + $b)*100)/100" | bc)
echo $result
```

That should give you the desired result of 0.055.

See https://askubuntu.com/questions/217570/bc-set-number-of-digits-after-decimal-point answer regarding how to handle scale with `bc`